# iexplore.exe process opens but I can't see it

Tags: internet-explorer, process, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a strange issue with opening IE (8), on Server 2008 R2, I execute the process (try to open a web-site in a browser) and I can see it in the Task Manager, but it's not visible on the Taskbar or anywhere on the desktop.
It is especially annoying since I use this server for developing a website.

It is the same if I open several IE processes, they are running (as seen in the taskbar) but are not visible.

After Restart of the server is usually works for a while till it starts this behaviour again.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread's remarks, perhaps you'll find a lead:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81aff6d2-5ffb-4064-8bde-ccc4322a00dd/multiple-instances-of-explorerexe-running-in-task-manager

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be Trojans as the following techspot article suggests:
http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/multiple-iexplorer-exe-instances-in-task-manager-trojans-found.188465/

but note that it talks about 32 bit version and you stated that you use win server 2k8 R2 which is strictly 64 bit...